# Equivalent of pmset noidle -u on Windows

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell, sleep, power-management

On OS X one can easily temporarily prevent the Mac from sleeping using the command:

```
pmset noidle -u
```

- `pmset` - manipulates power managment settings
- `noidle` - flag stands for sleep prevention method
- `u` - simulates user activity

How can the equivalent effect can be achieved in Windows 7 using `cmd` or `Powershell` without any additional software?

Comment: *"in Windows 7 with cmd.exe **without any additional software**"* I doubt that is possible. `cmd.exe` is pretty dumb. As an aside, your example on Mac OS X *clearly* relies on software external to the shell and terminal (I very much doubt that `type pmset` will respond `pmset is a shell builtin` or something to that effect).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Powershell based solution could work as well, wouldn't it be possible just to put together a loop in cmd that would do something meaningless but not tax the system much.

Comment: @Konrad Please don't use `[tag:xxx]` in the question body. It's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: via powercfg**

Disable Standby/Sleep

```
powercfg -x -standby-timeout-dc 0
powercfg -x -standby-timeout-ac 0
```

Disable Hibernation

```
powercfg -x -hibernate-timeout-dc 0
powercfg -x -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
```

**Option 2: simulate keypress**

Save the following as sendkey.js

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
while (true) {
    WshShell.SendKeys ("{SCROLLLOCK}{SCROLLLOCK}");
    WScript.Sleep(60000);
}
```

Use in an interactive shell:
`cscript sendkey.js`, then <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to terminate.

Or run in an window:
`start /min "awake" cscript sendkey.js`, then close window or 
`taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq awake" /im cscript.exe` to terminate.

A caveat is that the script sends key to the active window, so make sure the key (<kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> in this case) does not trigger unwanted side effect.

Reference:
[Power management through the Terminal (No more automatic Sleep!)](http://blog.coretech.dk/mip/power-management-trough-the-ts-no-more-automatic-sleep)
[How to disable sleep mode via CMD?](https://superuser.com/questions/368022/how-to-disable-sleep-mode-via-cmd)
[Press Keyboard keys using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file)
[Prevent desktop lock or screensaver with PowerShell](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2009/06/29/prevent-desktop-lock-or-screensaver-with-powershell)

Comment: Alternative if permissions are disabled?

Comment: does [this freeware](http://www.softwareok.com/?Microsoft/DontSleep) works for you?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I'm interested in exploring whether this can be done within a standard system configuration without external software

Comment: Very much to the point, may work. If of interest, feel free to draft an update on those basis, will be happy to accept.