# Prevent windows 10 from sleeping for next lid closing only

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, sleep, power-management

Sometimes I let my computer (Lenovo laptop under Windows 10) do stuff that takes a while (e.g. scientific computation). When it does that, I would like to be able to close its lid without it going to sleep.

The problem is that I would also like to keep it’s default behavior where it goes to sleep when I close it, most of the time.

The way I’d like it to work would be that, if I don’t do anything and close the lid, it goes to sleep. If I press some arbitrary key combination though, it would ignore the next time I close the lid, and stay awake until I open it again.

Ideally, this behavior would be the same plugged in or not. I know I can change that under «power management», but I do that often, and it would be nice to have a shortcut for it.

Can anybody think of a way to do that, or any trick to emulate this kind of behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the computer from sleeping, you could use a program such as
[Caffeine](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/)
or
[Insomnia](https://dlaa.me/Insomnia/).

Alternatively, you may disable sleep on lid close and re-enable it later.
If doing so manually is too onerous, you can do that via a command that
you may put in a batch file stored on the desktop.

See the toggle script, for disabling and restoring the lid close action
to whatever it was before, in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/909945/8672)
(but the other answers might also be pertinent).

Here is a slightly modified version of the script :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:(" %%i in ('powercfg /GETACTIVESCHEME') do set ACTIVESCHEME=%%i
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:(" %%i in ('powercfg -q %ACTIVESCHEME% SUB_BUTTONS LIDACTION ^| findstr "[0-9a-z]*-[0-9a-z]*-[0-9a-z]*-[0-9a-z]*-[0-9a-z]*"') do set FULLPATH=!FULLPATH! %%i
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:(" %%i in ('powercfg /q %FULLPATH% ^| findstr "[0-9]x[0-9]*"') do (
    set CURRENTSETTINGAC=!CURRENTSETTINGDC!
    set CURRENTSETTINGDC=%%i
)
set CURRENTSETTINGAC=%CURRENTSETTINGAC:~-1%
set CURRENTSETTINGDC=%CURRENTSETTINGDC:~-1%
powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX %FULLPATH% 0
powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX %FULLPATH% 0
powercfg /s %ACTIVESCHEME%
pause Waiting to re-enable sleep on lid close ...
powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX %FULLPATH% %CURRENTSETTINGAC%
powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX %FULLPATH% %CURRENTSETTINGDC%
powercfg /s %ACTIVESCHEME%
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you very much! I'm probably going to find out easily, but anyone knows a way to execute a batch file via custom global shortcut?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom global shortcut" ?

Comment: I mean a custom keyboard shortcut that I could press at anytime to launch the script, without having to go click on the batch file.

Comment: [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) is your friend. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script).

Comment: exactly what I needed too! I use this with Plex Media Server with its setting to activate Away Mode, now when I close the lid, my PC won't immediately go to Sleep, and not later either because I also changed normal Sleep (after a delay) to prevent Sleep only go to Away Mode with Power Options > Multimedia settings > When sharing media > Allow the computer to enter Away Mode + Sleep > Allow Away Mode Policy > Yes. I have searched how to properly do that for a long time! I just had to change the q option to qh to read correct setting because LIDACTION in the SUB_BUTTONS group is a hidden setting